# How to add two floats in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I started to learn NASM a few days ago so there are many things that I don't know about NASM. I am trying to add two floats, from user input.

I found a code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181811/how-to-add-two-numbers-integer-and-a-float-in-nasm) question that prints the result but I want to store it. As I read from [here](https://redirect.cs.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/313/fall04/burt_katz/lectures/Lect12/floatingpoint.html), the result is stored in ST0, I don't understand where actually it is, but I can't assign the result to a variable. The code I found from the question :

```
sub esp, 8          
mov dword [esp], 2   
fild dword [esp]     
mov dword [esp], __float32__(3.25) ;
fadd dword [esp]
```

And I tried :

```
mov eax, dword [esp]
mov dword [res], eax
```

But it didn't produce any output.

How can I do that on NASM?

Comment: `And I tried :` You're reading from [esp]. Thats not ST0. Try [`fst`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fst:fstp)

Comment: I tried this but it produced a wrong result (64.000015) :
`sub esp, 8 
mov dword [esp], 2  
fild dword [esp]     
mov dword [esp], __float32__(3.25) ;
fadd dword [esp]    
fst dword [res]`

Comment: That looks right to me.  Are you sure you're looking at `res` correctly, as a single-precision float with your debugger?  If you're passing it to printf, remember that `%f` takes a `double` arg.  Check `st0` right after the `fadd` with a debugger, too (before `fstp`.  Well, you're using `fst`, not popping the x87 stack, so you can check after.)

Comment: I defined `res` at `section .bss` as `res: resb 4` and used `push dword [res]` to print. I tried to change it to `resq 4` but it still prints the same. And when I try to change `push dword [res]` to `push qword [res]`, it throws `instruction not supported in 32-bit mode `.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how you convert a `float` to a `double`.  You have to actually convert, not copy more bytes past the end of the float32.  Look at what a compiler would do: https://godbolt.org/z/WG17Gjvj9 (using GAS .intel_syntax; to translate to NASM, dword ptr becomes dword, etc.)